# Why is my global array not working when called under my function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

If I declare my global array outside the functions, the `alert()` codes won't work. But if I placed it inside my function, it would. My goal here is to have a global array that I could use within my functions without creating or clearing existing data inside it.

```
var userP = new Array();
var userS = new Array();
var userQ = new Array();

function pressButton(){
  var p = document.getElementById("exampleModalLongTitle").innerHTML;
  var s = $( "#myChoice option:selected" ).text();
  var q = document.getElementById("number").value;
  userP.push(p);
  userS.push(s);
  userQ.push(q);
  alert(userP[0]);
  alert(userS[0]);
  alert(userQ[0]);
}


<body>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" onclick="myCart()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">My Cart</a>
  </li>
  <select name="choice" id="myChoice" onchange="changeFunc()">
  <input type="text" id="number" value="0" style="text-align: center;"/>
</body>
```

Comment: `alert()` does't support a `,` seperate value.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert. And please post workable code or trigger event of `addCart`

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (preferable as executable snippet -> `< >`)

Comment: @Andreas changed it into a more simple code. hope you could help, thanks! :(

Comment: The [snippet works as-is](https://jsfiddle.net/706h1ksn/) -> [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Did you have a look at the links? Because that's not a [mcve] :/